# using dynamic table to fill data only and pass the values to code behind ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

It's been a long time since I coded so I am facing troubles.

I am using VS2015 .NET c# webForms Application. I have a simple form where the user need to fill a dynamic table and after hitting submit the values are passed to code behind for some calculation then stored in DB.

I used the HTML table in the link http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/add-edit-and-delete-rows-from-table-dynamically-using-javascript.php

the output:
[image]

I cant use Gridview becuase it postsback and connects to DB directly. I dont want to store the input of the table immediately.

I am stuck at retrieving the data from HTML table.
Can I get some hints or suggest to me any other better way to do if any.

If you want I can provide the code.
Thanks

UPDATE:
my code

form.aspx

```
   <form runat="server">
   //elements here

   <div class="table-responsive" id="div_invlv">

               <!------TABLE ---->
          <table  id="data_table" class="table" >
           <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th>   </th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Position</th>
           <th>Company</th>
           <th></th>
           </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>
                   <select class="form-control" id="type_of_person">
                     <option>Internal</option>
                     <option>External</option>
                   </select>   </td>
               <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_name" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_position"  /></td>
               <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_company"  /></td>
               <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-template-main add"  onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row" /></td>
            </tr>

            </table>
   </form>
```

Table.js

```
   function delete_row(no)
   {
   document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
   }

    function add_row()
  {
  var drop = document.getElementById("type_of_person");
  var new_type = drop.options[drop.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  var new_name=document.getElementById("new_name").value;
  var new_country=document.getElementById("new_position").value;
  var new_company=document.getElementById("new_company").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'><td id='id_row" + table_len + "'><asp:Label Name='id" + table_len + "' runat='server' > " + table_len + "</asp:Label></td>   <td id='Type_row" + table_len + "'><asp:Label ID='type" + table_len + "' runat='server' > " + new_type + "</asp:Label></td><td id='name_row" + table_len + "'> <asp:Label ID='name'"+table_len+" runat='server' >" + new_name + "</asp:Label></td><td id='position_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_country + "</asp:Label></td><td id='company_row" + table_len + "'><asp:Label ID='company'"+table_len+" runat='server' >" + new_company + "</asp:Label></td><td > <input type='button' value='Delete' class='btn btn-small btn-template-main delete' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'></td></tr>";


    document.getElementById("new_name").value="";
    document.getElementById("new_position").value = "";
    document.getElementById("new_company").value = "";
   }
```

C#

```
   string typeTable = Request.Form["type" + 1];
   Label10.Text = typeTable ;
```

The rows are generated during the run and I am trying to retrieve the value of one cell in the first row for testing but its not working.

Comment: post your code to see what you have so far or better: to see where you are stuck.

Comment: "I am stuck at retrieving the data from HTML table", that is because from the server side you have no access to the HTML table, only form elements.You need to be persisting the table data in hidden form fields. The other option is to style the form fields to look like regular cells and set them to `readonly`

Comment: @Legends the code is posted.

Comment: @JonP I am adding asp controls using js code. but I still don't know how to retrieve them and loop through them as they are created during the run.

Comment: You have db connecting code in your page_load? why you do not want it to postback? or i misunderstood the problem?

Comment: @JKOU The form has many elements to be filled. and the dynamic table is in the middle. postback will store all the data once its entered in the table and I dont want to store any data until the user complete the form and hit submit. if there is a way to use gridview to display data and store it later?

Comment: the problem is since the table rows are created through javascript, you cant access its rows values directly in code behind, they will not considered as populated, i tested it myself with normal html table or <asp:table>, if you can somehow change when the elements are filled or bind it to a button (an asp:button function) you can save yourself a lot of trouble

Comment: This should help:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-Add-Rows-to-GridView-using-JavaScript-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Are you open to using the jquery library to streamline your javascript?

Comment: You also can't add asp.net webform controls using javascript in a functional manner, these controls need to be served via the .net engine.

Comment: @JonP I will use whatever to make it work.

Comment: @Legends this seems helpful. I will try it it and update the post

Comment: @JKOU thanx for your comment I can see the issue now. I will try the method in the link provided by Legends

Comment: @Legends the links works great!! its what I need. now I am trying to figure out how to make the delete button works. Thans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link provided by @legends

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-Add-Rows-to-GridView-using-JavaScript-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet.aspx

works great and solved most of my issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to fill your datagrid dyamically

```
public void fillgrid(string qry, GridView dg){

        try
        {

            sql.cmd = new SqlCommand("qry", sql.cn);
            sql.cn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql.cmd);
            sda.Fill(ds);
            dg.DataSource = ds;
            dg.DataBind();
            sql.cn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());


        }

    }
```

or you can use a placeholder control to create a dyamic html table

Comment: I want the user to fill the data,the table is empty in its initial. what do you mean by "placeholder" cuz I am using a dynamic html table